# Python - Propagating added base class functionalty to subclasses

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, subclass

Say I am using a shape-drawing framework with the following classes:

```
 class Shape(ABC):
  movable: False

  @abstractmethod
  def movePoint(pointId, newX, newY): pass

class Rect(Shape):
  aspectLocked: False

  # Implement abstract function
  def movePoint(pointId, newX, newY): pass

class Hexagon(Shape): pass
  # ...
```

I want to use `Rect`, `Hexagon`, etc. in my code, but I want each to have a `fill()` method. However, `fill()` can work at the `Shape` level, so I end up doing this:

```
def _shapeFill(self):
  pass

class MyRect(Rect):
  def fill(self):
    return _shapeFill(self)

# Same procedure for Hexagon, etc.
```

I can also do

```
for shape in [Rect, Hexagon]:
  shape.fill = _shapeFill
```

But editors like PyCharm don't recognize `fill()` as a class method and I don't know if this solution is robust.

Basically, I want to extend `Shape` AND have that extended method available in the `Rect` class without having to redefine `Rect`. Is there a pythonic solution?

Bonus points if someone can tell me the technical name for this, since I didn't know what term to Google. Thanks!

Comment: This is called "monkey-patching". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just attach it to the ABC:

```
Shape.fill = _shapefill
```

If you want to play more nicely with IDEs and code analysis, you could define your extra methods in a mixin class which you inherit from in custom shape classes:

```
class ShapeMixin:
    def fill(self):
        pass

class MyRect(Rect, ShapeMixin):
    pass
```

This is basically your first solution, but expressed a little more cleanly.

Comment: This works better than my second solution, thanks. Is there a good way to tell editors like PyCharm that `fill` is a `Shape` method? Currently the autocomplete doesn't recognize it for subclases.

Comment: @ntjess I'm not sure about that - seems like a very hard thing to do in general. If you want better completion, you could put it on a mixin class that you inherit from; see my edited answer.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for. Thanks! I wasn't sure if multiple inheritance would play nicely with the setup but it looks like it works well here.